# How do I keep my navbar hamburger on the same stop when the parent gets bigger?

Tags: html, css, navbar

title kind of says it. When my navbar is opened, the X goes to the middle of the parent green div. I want it to stay at the same place as the normal bars. Here is a live demo: *link hidden* The CSS is in styles/city.css and scroll down to see the `hamburger`, `bar` and `mapNav`: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QQFfA.png

[Navbar closed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mPIlo.png)

[Where X is, but where it should be in red](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O1glH.png)

Thanks in advance,

- JT

Comment: Is class="mapNavOpen" defined  in your style sheet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code snippet would be a bit more elegant with your HTML, but add the following CSS to your code:

`margin-left: auto;` sets the highest possible margin to the left, so the hamburger menu is all the way to the right.
The whole container is `50px`, the width of the hamburger menu is `25px`, which means the `margin-left` value is `25px`. Apply the half of that margin to `margin-right: 12.5px`, that way the hamburger menu is centered when closed and remains intact.

```css
.hamburger {
    display: block;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding-top: 10px;
    width: 25px;
    /* Remove this */
    /* margin: auto; */
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: 12.5px;
}
```

Also for next time, make sure to include your code! It's much easier to help you then.

Answer (score 1):

This may not be the best way but it will work. Add this to your css.

```
.hamburger.active .bar {
    position: relative;
    left: 124px;
}
```

Comment: It doesn't look very pleasant. I want it to stay there.